Tax Implications for a German Resident with Freelance Income from a UK-Based Company Paid to an Indian Account
I'm an Indian national who relocated to Germany in December 2023. While I receive my primary salary in a German bank account, I also freelance for a UK-based company, with those earnings deposited into my Indian bank account. Since I'm not a UK resident, no taxes are withheld from my UK income, and I currently pay taxes on this income in India. Should I also declare this income in Germany? What are the tax implications, and which option would provide the most tax relief?

Why do you think the income is taxable in India? Are you a tax resident of India?

Note that apart from taxes your German employer might need to agree (in writing) on you having a secondary job and there are restrictions on your total number of working hours for both jobs combined. If your primary German salary is for a fulltime 40 hours per week job your secondary job is almost guaranteed to push you over the legal limits in terms of work time.


Should I also declare this income in Germany?

Income earned in Germany is taxable to Germany. It doesn't matter where the payer is, or where the bank is. Income is earned where the services are performed (i.e.: where you are physically located while doing the work).
Whether or not you should be paying taxes in India depends on your status in India. If you're still a tax resident in India, you may be liable for taxes there as well. There might be a tax treaty between India and Germany to allow for relief from double taxation in that case, and you'll need to follow the treaty to figure out what taxes you're liable for and where.

India also has a foreign tax credit that can be used for relief from double taxation even if there is no tax treaty.
